# Show user id's profile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have problem with user profile. I mean with that i'd like to look for user profile ( example: im user 1 but i want to look for user 2's profile ) but if i write in Url (example: localhost/$userID nothing change in profile page just show informations from me- user 1 )

Here is my HTML CODE for user's profile:

```html
<table style="height:70px" class='table table-bordered table-hover table-striped'>
  <tr>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Username</b></td>
    <td><b><?php echo $row['userName']; ?></b></td>     

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Name</b></td>
    <td>.......</td>        

  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Gender</b></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['sex']; ?></td>     

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Nickname</b></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nickname']; ?></td>        

  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Rank</b></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Rank']; ?></td>        

  </tr></table>
```

Here is my php code i use for user_ID:

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
 $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

And in my URL says like that:

```html
<li><a href='profil.php?=<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>=<?php echo $row['userName']; ?>'></li>
```

I was looking on internet for examples but i don't really know what i'm missing in my code

Little help from you guys would be very welcome :p

Comment: your using the id from the session, not the url

Comment: @Dagon okey now i can look for other users but here is another problem...when i look for user_id 2 is change name to user_id 2 (here is an example: https://gyazo.com/c4ead5b6d916babb35100b65e855e2e7

Comment: use the session for the viewer, the url id for the displayed profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the WHERE clause in your SQL query
instead of using `$_SESSION['userSession']` you could use `$_GET['id']` and in your link to profiles use `profil.php?id=X` where X is the user ID of the person whose profile you want to see.

So a link for someone to see their own profile would be:
`<a href="profil.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['userSession'];">My Profile</a>`

Make sure to use `is_numeric` to validate the user-input and have a default message for if there is no user with that ID.

Comment: okey now i can look for other users but here is another problem...when i look for user_id 2 is change name to user_id 2 (here is an example: https://gyazo.com/c4ead5b6d916babb35100b65e855e2e7

Comment: @Hartman It looks like you are using a function to get the username from an ID, could you post that code? I imagine you are sending the wrong ID as a parameter

Comment: @Michael O Maolain sure i will post it as answer on a question cuz here code thing doesn't work :S or here code as image https://gyazo.com/ab9f60faf273c463366a93e9fadc1e8d

Comment: @Hartman What you need to do is use `$_SESSION['userSession']` for showing the logged in user, and then for the user-profile use `$_POST['id']` - don't use either twice

Comment: @Michael O Maolain yeah now it's working but how can i use userid's username for showing the loggedin user?

Comment: @Hartman I don't understand what you mean, do you want to show an arbitrary user profile or the profile of the logged-in user?

Comment: @Michael O Maolain i want to show both on the same page understand?

Comment: @Hartman You will have to call your function to display the username twice. Once for the user profile and then again for the logged in user

Comment: @Michael O Maolain well i'm trying to do that but don't get it so well :D thank you anyway for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100069/discussion-between-hartman-and-micheal-o-maolain).

Answer (score 1):

your using the id from the session, not the url

change

```
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
```

to

```
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_GET['id']));
```

now you have the id from the url, the id of the use you want to see.

and the url to

```
<a href='profil.php?id=<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>
```

added `id=` standard practice, if you just want `?99` you can get the string in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`